# Unable to browse private key in PuTTY

Tags: ssh, putty

I am trying to connect to server using PuTTY through SSH. But unable to add a private key as there is no browse option showing. I tried reinstalling PuTTY but showing same.

[image: PuTTY configuration window]

Answer (score 7):

Since PuTTY 0.78, the *Private key file for authentication* box has been moved further deep in panel hierarchy to *Connection > SSH > Auth **> Credentials***:

[image]

---

This is also documented in PuTTY FAQ:
[Since 0.78, I can't find where to configure my SSH private key](https://the.earth.li/%7Esgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/AppendixA.html#faq-privkey-control-moved)